# Getting Error "PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_VALUE' must be declared" in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to extract data from Json file stored in a table. But I am not able to execute the package JSON_VALUE inside PL/SQL.

Below query works fine:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{a:100}', '$.a' ) AS value
  FROM DUAL;
```

But Below PL/SQL block doesn't work:

```
declare 
  SQL_QUERY_RES varchar2(300);
  cursor c1 is
  SELECT 1 from DUAL;
begin
   for i in c1 
   loop
     SQL_QUERY_RES :=  JSON_VALUE('{a:100}', '$.a' );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( SQL_QUERY_RES );    
   end loop;
   COMMIT;
end;
/
```

It gives **PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_VALUE' must be declared** Error.

Comment: Is your DB version 12c ..? thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. Works for 12.2 but not for 12.1. If your version is 12.1 consider using within a query as in the Tejash's answer.

Comment: Works for me on 12.2 and also on DbFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=157f639e67a2898debe1ad0157b5b624

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan   My DB version is 12.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE
    SQL_QUERY_RES   VARCHAR2(300);
    CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        DUAL;

BEGIN
    FOR I IN C1 LOOP
        -- USE THIS
        SELECT
            JSON_VALUE('{a:100}', '$.a')
        INTO SQL_QUERY_RES
        FROM
            DUAL;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL_QUERY_RES);
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

It is working for me.

For DB version `12.1`, PL/SQL assignment `SQL_QUERY_RES :=  JSON_VALUE('{a:100}', '$.a' );` doesn't work, you need to use within a select statement, but for `12.2` works.